# Show accepted (but not published) paper to potential advisor

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, paper-submission

It is time for me to apply for graduate studies.

I am wondering, if I have a paper accepted at a journal or conference, is it OK for me to show this accepted paper to others (such as potential advisor for my graduate study) even if the journal or conference has not yet formally published (or made public) this paper?

Comment: Related: [Do I need to attach the letter of acceptance of an accepted paper along with the paper itself to my CV for applications to phd programs?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29820/do-i-need-to-attach-the-letter-of-acceptance-of-an-accepted-paper-along-with-the)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, I would think so, but I suppose this depends somewhat upon the culture of the field that you are in. To be on the safe side, simply check with your co-authors and get their permission beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

In CS, I think this is pretty normal - in fact I think this can be considered normal in any field.

I mean an accepted paper is going to be published at some point of time in the respective conference or journal. So the effect of sharing such a paper should theoretically have the same impact as sharing a paper that has been published.

Comment: Sadly, in the biosciences sharing without permission of coauthors could actually be a breach of trust even when the paper is accepted but not yet published. Without knowing what field the OP is in, we have to recommend playing it safe.

Comment: Yes. Definitely. Permission of coauthors I assumed was a condition that was implicitly met. I don't think I'm misunderstanding this if I say that the coauthors should normally be delighted to help one out in such a scenario and grant permission.